# Time is not synchronized when using savevm feature in Qemu

Tags: c, linux, embedded, virtual-machine, qemu

I am using **savevm sanp** feature to save snapshots, but once I loaded the snapshot that was saved using this feature, I find the time is not synchronized, how to solve this issue?

```
/usr/bin/qemu-system-i386 -m 1024 -monitor stdio -loadvm snap test.qcow2 -netdev user,id=hostnet0,hostfwd=tcp::1200-:22 -rtc base=localtime,clock=host -device e1000,netdev=hostnet0
```

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or configuring Linux apps. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I will post it in another area!